# AsyncTask does not progress to onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-webview, jsoup

I'm using `AsyncTask` to load a `div` in a `WebView`, while displaying a `ProgressDialog`.
The content is loaded and the `ProgressDialog` gets displayed, but it doesn't disappear because the execution does not enter `onPostExecute()`. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
package xx.xxx.xxx;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewsActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView wView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_main);

        new LoadNews().execute("");
    }

    private class LoadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = "http://www.example.com/example";

            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements ele = doc.select("div#examplediv");

                String html = ele.toString();
                String mime = "text/html";
                String encoding = "utf-8";

                wView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvNews);
                wView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, html, mime, encoding, null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            Dialog.setMessage("please wait...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)    
        {
            try
            {
                if(Dialog.isShowing())
                {
                    Dialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Your `AsyncTask` Class implementation is wrong..

There are lots of mistakes in your code,

1. You are trying to Access UI (WebView) in `doInBackground()` which doesn't allowed in Android. As doInBackground runs in worker thread, while your Activity Ui (WebView) is in MainUI Thread.
2. The argument of `onPostExecute()` and return type of `doInBackground()` doesn't match.

Please Go trough the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Class from Android Developers and get Basic Fundamental of How it works..

Comment: specifically use protected void onPostExecute(String unused)    not void

Comment: As its not possible to give you complete code for `AsyncTask` class. Better to learn yourself so you can understand of flow and implementation which will helps you in future.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code you have created your `ProgressDialog` inside the `AsyncTask`. If you look at the [documentation of `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can see that you should only handle UI elements through the `onPostExecute` method and this goes for the `WebView` as well.

I would suggest you get the references to the UI elements in your `onCreate` method after you have defined the variables outside the `onCreate` method so that they can be accessed by other methods as well. Furthermore you should define and instantiate your `ProgressDalog` just before executing your `AsyncTask` in the `onCreate` method. Then dismiss the dialog in the `onPostExecute` method.